# Changing velocity of a fixed object

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a robot hand model with fingers that are torque controlled. The hand floats and has the task of grasping objects. So far the hand was first fixed to the world (with a revolute joint). Now I would like to add more degrees of freedom in order to allow for the hand to move freely by being able to set the velocities of the base.

The problem is that when I disable the revolute joint to be able to do this, the counter torques from the fingers make the whole model move. What I would like to have is to be able to move the hand around, but to make it act as it is fixed, i.e. to prevent the effects of counter torques to influence it (e.g. just be able to change the linear velocity of the base of the hand, but ignore all the forces acting on it). Is there a way to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17269/changing-velocity-of-a-fixed-object/) by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 40 on 2017-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After going through the SDF reference, I found the [kinematic](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=link#link_kinematic) tag that accomplishes what I wanted. Also, setting this tag allows me to not even have to have the revolute joint mentioned earlier when I simple want the link to be fixed to the world.

---

Originally posted by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) with karma: 40 on 2017-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-09-15**:
Glad to know you found a solution and that the kinematic tag actually works :)